# How can I overwrite the value of a field in a bundle class?

Tags: views, nodes

In Drupal 9 I would like to know if it is possible to overwrite the value of a field in a BundleClass. Looking at the Drupal API, I see that it is common to use either `hook_entity_view_alter` or `hook_views_pre_render`. The only way I have found is to define a new method:

```php
public function getUpdateFieldName() {
  $value = this->get('field_name')->getValue();
  # Code here ...
  return $code
}
```

However, with this example, I have to create a pseudo-field to be able to get the value in a view. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

To query field values Views operates on SQL basis, to display you can configure a Views field plugin and additionally use the Field API field formatter. These are the two classes you should consider to add PHP code, if you can't use the rewrite options Views field plugins provide out-of-the-box.

From there you can refactor the code and put the bundle specific calculations in the bundle class.